# Removing default migrations from Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-migrations

After creating a new Laravel project with `laravel new`, there are a couple of migration files in the `database > migrations` folder:

```
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
```

These seem to be examples of typically useful migrations and are probably a good place to start if you need a system that requires something similar. However I'd like to delete them so they don't clash with something in a new project I'm building.

I was hoping I would be just able to delete the files, as I've not run `php artisan migrate` yet, but when I try my IDE says:

[image]

Why are these files already tied into the system, and how can I safely remove them? Is there some documentation on the Laravel site that I've not been able to find about this?

I guess I could ignore the warning and try running `composer dump-autoload -o`, but is this really OK?

Comment: If you haven't ran you migrations yet you are safe to delete them. Ignore your IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are these files already tied into the system

to map all project classes

> how can I safely remove them?

Ignore  IDE and delete them then run  `composer dump-autoload` and will remap project classes

> Is there some documentation on the Laravel site that I've not been
>   able to find about this?

i don't see any thing about this in laravel documentation site

Comment: Sweet. That worked. All references from the code were removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the warnings and delete them. The migrations that come out of the box are to help you get started with basic auth. You don't necessarily need them. Run `composer dump-autoload` when you're done.